# How can I edit developer options by code?

Tags: java, android

Can I edit developer's options like ADB debugging and animation speed by code?

Comment: At best, you might on a rooted device.

Comment: My device is rooted.

Comment: Might be possible doing funky stuff using the Xposed framework? I know you can toggle application debug flag with the XInstaller module.

Comment: In fact this is not the way i wanted to do it. Idealy i want to get this code working on any device (rooted or non-rooted)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for [Apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/).

- Disassembling resources to nearly original form (including resources.arsc, classes.dex, 9.png. and XMLs)
- Rebuilding decoded resources back to binary APK/JAR
- Organizing and handling APKs that depend on framework resources
- Smali Debugging
- Helping with repetitive tasks

Comment: No. That's not what I am looking for.

Comment: Well, can you please explain what you are looking for?